# Python Regex non greedy way to match/select string within quotes but string sometimes contains brackets, comma, backslash and pull stops

Tags: python, regex

I want to match these lines
line1:
`,["0x3bad08fb87bc906f:0x74d6f6242d49ab18","SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education)",null,[null,null,12.784799699999999,78.7137085]`
line2:
`,["0x3bad08e4f337028d:0x5635e172ff9d7570","Sudha Nursery \u0026 Primary School",null,[null,null,12.7849528,78.7159848]`
line3:
`,["0x3bad08e6a3dfe635:0x4ea2fcc42c9f7ce","As-Shukoor School",null,[null,null,12.7854174,78.7196367]`

My observation is that each line starts with comma(,), ends with square bracket closed (]), three occurrences of "null" and then two numbers with decimal places from 5 to 16.
All I want is to extract the string within quotes and the two numbers at the end with decimal places.

I figured little bit but confused how to match withing quotes which sometimes include brackets, pullstops, backslash, spaces, commas, minus sign, *
Here is my half completed expression/pattern

`(r'^\,\[\"0x[0-9a-z]{16}:0x[0-9a-z]{16}\"\,\"(.*?)\"\,null\,\[null\,null\,(\d\d\.\d{5,16})\,(\d\d\.\d{5,16})\]')`

but this doesn't work.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex with flags `re.M`:

```
^,\["0x[a-f0-9]{16}:0x[a-f0-9]{16}","([^"]*)",null,\[null,null,(\d+\.\d{5,16}),(\d+\.\d{5,16})\]$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cfwsLP/1/)

Most everything in the above regex is straightforward. To match the quoted string, I am assuming that the string itself does not contain a `"` character. So I used ...

```
"([^"]*)"
```

... which matches 0 or more non-# characters within double-quotes and places those characters in capture group 1. This is a much more efficient alternative to `"(.*?)"`

```py
import re

lines = """,["0x3bad08fb87bc906f:0x74d6f6242d49ab18","SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education)",null,[null,null,12.784799699999999,78.7137085]
,["0x3bad08e4f337028d:0x5635e172ff9d7570","Sudha Nursery \u0026 Primary School",null,[null,null,12.7849528,78.7159848]
,["0x3bad08e6a3dfe635:0x4ea2fcc42c9f7ce","As-Shukoor School",null,[null,null,12.7854174,78.7196367]
"""

rex = re.compile(r'^,\["0x[a-f0-9]{16}:0x[a-f0-9]{16}","([^"]*)",null,\[null,null,(\d+\.\d{5,16}),(\d+\.\d{5,16})\]$', re.M)
for m in rex.finditer(lines):
    print(m[1], m[2], m[3])
```

Prints:

```
SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education) 12.784799699999999 78.7137085
Sudha Nursery & Primary School 12.7849528 78.7159848
```

It will *not* match line 3 since `0x4ea2fcc42c9f7ce` only contains 15 "nibbles" (half-bytes).

**Update**

If you assume that each line should be matched and you would like a more lenient regex because there could be some variation in the lines (for example, inserted whitespace), then you might wish to use this (with flags `re.M`):

```
^,[^[]*\["0x[a-f0-9]+:0x[a-f0-9]+"[^"]*"([^"]*)"\D*(\d+\.\d{5,16}),(\d+\.\d{5,16})
```

1. `^` match start of line
2. `[^[]*` match 0 or more non `[` characters
3. `[` match a `[`
4. `"0x[a-f0-9]+:0x[a-f0-9]+"` match quoted hex strings of arbitrary length separated by `:`
5. `[^"]*` match 0 or more non `"` characters
6. `"([^"]*)"` match quoted string in capture group 1
7. `\D*` match 0 or more non-digits
8. `(\d+\.\d{5,16})` match decimal number in capture group 2
9. `,` match a `,`
10. `(\d+\.\d{5,16})` match decimal number in capture group 3

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/39fkqO/1/)

```py
import re

lines = """,["0x3bad08fb87bc906f:0x74d6f6242d49ab18","SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education)",null,[null,null,12.784799699999999,78.7137085]
,["0x3bad08e4f337028d:0x5635e172ff9d7570","Sudha Nursery \u0026 Primary School",null,[null,null,12.7849528,78.7159848]
,["0x3bad08e6a3dfe635:0x4ea2fcc42c9f7ce","As-Shukoor School",null,[null,null,12.7854174,78.7196367]
"""

rex = re.compile(r'^,[^[]*\["0x[a-f0-9]+:0x[a-f0-9]+"[^"]*"([^"]*)"\D*(\d+\.\d{5,16}),(\d+\.\d{5,16})', re.M)
for m in rex.finditer(lines):
    print(m[1], m[2], m[3])
```

Prints

```
SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education) 12.784799699999999 78.7137085
Sudha Nursery & Primary School 12.7849528 78.7159848
As-Shukoor School 12.7854174 78.7196367
```

**Update 2**

And if you want to be really lenient, assuming every line should be matched:

```
^[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*"([^"]*)"\D*(\d+\.\d+)\D*(\d+\.\d+)
```

1. `^` match start of line
2. `[^"]*"[^"]*"` skip to and match first string
3. `[^"]*"([^"]*)"` skip to and match second string and place in capture group 1
4. `\D*(\d+\.\d+)` skip to next digit and capture decimal number in capture group 2.
5. `\D*(\d+\.\d+)` skip to next digit and capture decimal number in capture group 3.

```py
import re

lines = """,["0x3bad08fb87bc906f:0x74d6f6242d49ab18","SRI VIVEKANANDA MATRIC HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL Ambur (Spiritual, Modern Scientific Education)",null,[null,null,12.784799699999999,78.7137085]
,["0x3bad08e4f337028d:0x5635e172ff9d7570","Sudha Nursery \u0026 Primary School",null,[null,null,12.7849528,78.7159848]
,["0x3bad08e6a3dfe635:0x4ea2fcc42c9f7ce","As-Shukoor School",null,[null,null,12.7854174,78.7196367]
"""

rex = re.compile(r'^[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*"([^"]*)"\D*(\d+\.\d+)\D*(\d+\.\d+).*$', re.M)
for m in rex.finditer(lines):
    print(m[1], m[2], m[3])
```

Comment: Thanks @Booboo. Seriously I didn't even notice line 3 having 15 nibbles, went on thinking every line had 16.. what if i want line 3 also?

Comment: Well, if the only possibilities are 15 and 16 then `r'^,\["0x[a-f0-9]{16}:0x[a-f0-9]{15,16} ... etc.` If you are not sure or you want to relax the conditions `r'^,\["0x[a-f0-9]+:0x[a-f0-9]+ ... etc.`, which just says 1 or more for each. Note that the above regex, based on yours, requires *very strict adherence* as far as the format is concerned. I will update the answer with an something that is more *lenient*.